# VS2022 - report project incompatible with current version of Visual Studio

Tags: reporting-services, report, designer, visual-studio-2022

Finally saw that there is "Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022" available for VS2022, which should by idea work as a report designer and open the existing reports. But it turns out all of the report projects now are unsupported/incompatible due to new version of VS. If the VS2019 will be installed, there everything will work.

And migration report is not very informative:

*The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=661331&projecttype=F14B399A-7131-4C87-9E4B-1186C45EF12D*

Any ideas how to make them work in VS2022? Maybe someone had similar experience?

[image: error on trying to error resolve]

**Solution**:
Thanks to the posted suggestion (marked green) managed to install 'Microsoft Reporting Services Projects' Version 3.0.1, which was crucial on VS2019, instead of the 'Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022'. That fixed my reporting issue, but due to outdated reporting solution. Probably will need to update it to newer one to avoid such legacy workarounds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to have early access to VS2022 release candidate builds before they are published to the VS Gallery, we’re making available to give customers an opportunity to provide feedback prior to finalizing releases. To access the release candidate of the extensions in Visual Studio, you may do so by creating a “private gallery” and entering the following settings.

Navigate to Tools > Options and then select Extensions and Updates under General.
Under "Additional Extension Galleries", enter the following details:
Name: Microsoft BI VSIX Preview
URL: http://aka.ms/ProBI-VSIX2022
After entering these settings, your "Extensions and Updates" dialog will show updates for the extension when there is a new release candidate that you can install to provide feedback for a day or two before the VS Gallery VSIX is updated.

Provide feedback and report issues with this Vsix Package or Reporting Services projects in general to: ProBIToolsFeedback@microsoft.com.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ProBITools.MicrosoftReportProjectsforVisualStudio&ssr=false#overview

Comment: Hi! Thanks for advice, but all of the extensions are up to date at the moment. Guess this won`t help much for now.

Comment: Although, I managed to install 'Microsoft Reporting Services Projects' Version 3.0.1, which was crucial on VS2019, instead of the 'Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022'. Now the reports are opening just fine! Thanks for the workaround ;)

Answer (score 24):

I faced a similar issue. I was working on my reports, closed VS2022 and trying to re-open the project, it was shown as "incompatible".

Go to Extensions -> Manage Extension -> Installed

In my case the 'Microsoft Reporting Services Projects' was disabled. Re-enable it, then close and re-open VS2022. If the project is still shown as "incompatible", reload it and it should solve the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's because recently they finally introduced full support, so this issue is now resolved completely as far as I am aware.

Comment: I was experiencing problems installing the extension as a whole through the Microsoft marketplace. However I downloaded it from Extensions -> Manage Extensions as you've suggested and this sorted out the issue.